# Windows Phone app crash on device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, silverlight-5.0, windows-phone-8-emulator

I make installed app on windows phone which crash but when I run in windows emulator it did not crash

I have button where I load page which have browser and I try to load there

- Code for button click

  ```
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      QueryString queryString = new QueryString { Parameter = "http://www.example.com/en/about" };
      App.RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(WebViewPage), queryString); 
  }
  ```
- onNavigatedTo of other Page

  ```
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
      QueryString param = e.Parameter as QueryString;
      Uri uri = new Uri(param.Parameter,UriKind.Absolute);
      webView.Navigate(uri);
  }
  ```

Not only it is happening with webview but also it is also happening with ListFlyOut control.

I don't know what is the issue but it is crashing on the device.

Comment: add internet permission on appmanifest and your problem solved

Comment: kindly can you give me some step. How I can do.

Comment: Open `Package.Appmanifest` and you can find it under `Capabilities` tab

Comment: That I have already given "Internet (Client & Server)" But Still it is not working :(

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2f9a0753-8f50-4f8e-8d68-d2a269a94a85/crash-in-webview-control-windows-phone-81-app?forum=wpdevelop Is this the issue ?

Comment: No I am not having scrolling issue, My page get crash before it get load

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88723/discussion-between-milind-and-soumya-sambit-kunda).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reset my Windows Phone and install again my app, voila all start working. With much better performance.

Comment: Tip: keep in mind that the parameter needs to be serializable. If not it can crash on suspension and activation